# Can not get the text after java script tag when using urllib

Tags: python, python-2.7, urllib

I am trying to get the html page using urllib.
Link : http://spys.one/en/socks-proxy-list/

```
<td colspan="1"><font class="spy1">1</font> <font class="spy14">178.197.249.213<script type="text/javascript">document.write("<font class=spy2>:<\/font>"+(e5b2l2^t0d4)+(o5p6w3^i9w3)+(d4m3m3^g7i9)+(o5p6w3^i9w3))</script><font class="spy2">:</font>1080</font></td>
```

I want to parse the ip address and the port. but the port is not extracted while requesting the url using urllib.

I am using centos 7. I tried using urllib2.

```
req = urllib.request.Request('http://spys.one/en/socks-proxy-list/')
```

Expected result should be same as the above.
In actual result I am not getting the port information after java script tag

Comment: It's blocked on my network buddy. What kinda sites are you scraping?

Answer (score 0):

The port is displayed using javascript.
You can use the following code to decode the javascript.

```
import requests
import re
from lxml import html

url = 'http://spys.one/en/socks-proxy-list/'
res = requests.get(url)

parser = html.fromstring(res.text)
rows = parser.xpath('//tr[@class="spy1xx"]/td/font[@class="spy14"]')
js = parser.xpath('//script[@type="text/javascript"]/text()')[0]
json_map = {i.split('=')[0]: i.split("=")[1][:1] for i in js.split(';')[-11:-1]}

proxy = []
for r in rows:
    ip = r.xpath('./text()')[0]
    try:
        script = r.xpath("./script/text()")[0]
    except IndexError:
        continue
    port_list = re.findall(r'\((\w{6})', script)
    port = ''.join([json_map[key] for key in port_list])
    proxy.append(ip + ":" + port)
print(proxy)
```